# How do I find HTML elements without IDs, by searching for them by other arbitrary identifiers?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css-selectors

Basically, I'm trying to find this element in a HTML doc. Not sure how to go about doing this, as there's no ID and I'm relatively new to DOM stuff. Anyone got any idea how to find the text of this ?

```
<strong ng-bind-html="gamePin" 
       data-functional-selector="game-pin" 
       class="ng-binding">6969696</strong>
```

Comment: What is the specific criteria that distinguishes this element from others?

Comment: Did you look at attribute selectors in the jQuery documentation?

Comment: Google "jQuery selectors"

Comment: Please don't post text as an image.

Comment: Sorry, @m69. I don't really use this site too often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tag name and attribute selectors, `document.querySelector()` or `document.querySelectorAll()`

```
let el = document.querySelectorAll("strong[data-functional-selector='game-pin']");
```

```
let selector = "strong[ng-bind-html='gamePin'][data-functional-selector='game-pin'][class='ng-binding']";
let el = document.querySelector(selector);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work.

```
$( "div:contains('6969696')" )
```

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable to assume that this element is the only, or first, .ng-binding in the entire document.

Comment: I'm not personally using jQuery in the project I'm working on, I just need to parse this page, thanks for the help though!

Comment: @Patrick Kenny: Wait, if you're not using jQuery, why did you tag your question [jquery]?

Comment: If you are not using jQuery, please got to https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/11/javascript-search-text-html-page/
There is a solution for this problem.

Comment: @BoltClock, because it uses the jQuery selectors, if I understand correctly(C/Python programmer trying out web stuff).

Comment: @Patrick Kenny: Ah, OK. jQuery borrows from the CSS standard, which is where selectors come from. So, rather than a jQuery selector, you want a CSS selector. jQuery is simply a library that implements selectors (and, notably, in a non-standard way). I'll retag your question.